# .sh query - running a ssh task

Tags: shell-script, ssh, terminal

This is on a macintosh but it's still unix command.

I am running some computers on a network that have file sharing turned off because of security so the only way to connect is via `ssh`.

I need to look at what applications are installed on the computers `/applications` folder so we can push our a few things.

What I would normally type in terminal would be:

```
ssh apple@192.168.1.117
(password)

cd /applications
ls -l
```

then this shows me all the applications installed in that folder.

Is there anyway to put that query into a `.sh` file to automate this? Like a `.bat` on windows when you can just double click it and it runs it.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but a side note:  You say "Like a `.bat` on windows when you can just double click it and it runs it", in order to be able to double click the `.sh` script to run it on OS X you will need to use the `.command` extension and make the script executable as described in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409946/how-do-i-make-this-file-sh-executable-via-double-click/9650209#9650209).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [public key authentication](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/)

In the source host run this only once:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa # ENTER to every field
ssh-copy-id myname@somehost
```

That's all, after that you'll be able to do ssh without password.

Coming to your question, use below command now,

```
ssh apple@192.168.1.117 'ls -l /applications'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command in a non-login, non-interactive shell session using `ssh`:

```
ssh apple@192.168.1.117 'ls -l /applications'
```

Comment: thank you, just needed the first bit though which i wasnt aware of.